# PHP Pear Mail not sending email

Tags: php, email, pear

I am having issues getting Pear Mail to send an email. I've enabled debug mode and here is the output:

```
DEBUG: Recv: 220 webhost.erhardt.tech ESMTP Postfix 
DEBUG: Send: EHLO localhost 
DEBUG: Recv: 250-webhost.erhardt.tech 
DEBUG: Recv: 250-PIPELINING 
DEBUG: Recv: 250-SIZE 30720000 
DEBUG: Recv: 250-VRFY 
DEBUG: Recv: 250-ETRN 
DEBUG: Recv: 250-AUTH PLAIN 
DEBUG: Recv: 250-AUTH=PLAIN 
DEBUG: Recv: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 
DEBUG: Recv: 250-8BITMIME 
DEBUG: Recv: 250 DSN 
DEBUG: Send: AUTH PLAIN 
DEBUG: Recv: 334 
DEBUG: Send: AHNpdGVAemxjYXJ0Y2MuY29tADNGfWVBQVg4bTk5SQ== 
DEBUG: Recv: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful 
DEBUG: Send: MAIL FROM: 
DEBUG: Recv: 250 2.1.0 Ok 
DEBUG: Send: RSET 
DEBUG: Recv: 250 2.0.0 Ok 
DEBUG: Send: QUIT DEBUG: Recv: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

My mail log only outputs these two lines.

```
Jun 26 03:11:20 webhost postfix/smtpd[8495]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jun 26 03:11:20 webhost dovecot: auth: mysql: Connected to 127.0.0.1 (mail)
Jun 26 03:11:20 webhost postfix/smtpd[8495]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

**Update**
Figured out the issue. Turns out it had nothing to do with the PEAR package or my mail server; The argument for the email was NULL and didn't notice until I turned error_reporting on.

Comment: How do you know that the email isn't sending? It looks like the email was sent. I've frequently had issues where I thought that emails weren't sending because they were being caught by spam filters because I was sending them from test domains / test servers.

Comment: @DanTruitt I don't receive it in my inbox. Not only are there no error messages in my logs, there are no messages saying the email was relayed.

Comment: I Figured out the issue. Updated the post.